# How to know the font used in a PDF file?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, truetype-fonts

I want to know what font is used in a [PDF](http://book.gitapress.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1318_Shriramcharitmanas_english_1-1200_final-updated_April-2019.pdf) file.
I use Foxit reader.

How can I find out which font has been used to make this document?

Comment: No matter which reader you use, you can see the font used in the document in the file properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open that pdf file on *Foxit Reader* and go to **File->Properties->Fonts**, at this point you now can know which the *fonts embedded* in one.

**Important:** There are **several fonts** in that document. For example, some those ones are *Helvetica, Heveltica-Bond*.

[image]

References:

- [3 Best Ways to Iden­ti­fy Fonts in PDF Files in Win­dows 10](https://www.guidingtech.com/identify-fonts-pdf-files-windows-10/)
- [4 Online Websites to identify Fonts in PDF files](https://teknologya.com/identify-fonts-in-pdf-files/)
- [Fonts in PDF files](https://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/fonts)

Comment: when I downloaded those font from internet I guess Chandan font is mainly used so upon copy pasting the text in Word with that font installed the text is garbled.

Comment: @politicalscience garbled text might be an artifact of the encoding or the formatting. Try first pasting the text into Notepad (which does no formatting), then copy it from Notepad and copy *that* into Word.
Also, some PDFs have (pseudo-)*kerning* issues - this is sometimes used as a form of protection. Can you describe (better still, screenshot) what "garbled" means?

Answer (score 2):

If the font is not already displayed in the application (status bar, info window, etc.), probably your best bet is to copy the PDF into another file and give it extension ".txt". Then open the new file using Notepad or some *simple* text editor.

You will see a lot of garbage mixed with small pieces of text. This is the internal structure of the PDF file, made up of objects organized in a hierarchy.

Look for the string "/BaseFont". You'll almost surely see several of them:

```
/BaseFont/TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT/FirstChar 32/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/Type/Font...
/BaseFont/Georgia#20Bold/FirstChar 0/LastChar 255/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding...
```

As you can see, the item immediately after the "/BaseFont" directive is the internal font name. The same operation, in a more reliable and professional way, is performed by several [software utilities](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor).

Otherwise, a different method is taking a screenshot of the PDF, and upload it onto some service like [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). This has the added advantage that you might be able to locate a font *similar* to the one you want, even if an exact match is not available.

Comment: Not that I'm complaining, but -- why is mine the accepted answer? I had assumed that Foxit Reader did not display this information, but unless @jluizsouzadev is mistaken, it does. I did provide some alternative means, but the correct answer is his.

Comment: I  learned something new in your answer so to encourage people to post with more knowledge I marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: Then in the interest of the readership, **upvote** my answer, and **accept** @jluizsouzadev . Acceptance means that theirs is the *best* answer, and upvoting means that I did contribute something. After all we don't want people to go Notepadding inside PDFs' when there's a simpler and easier way to do things :-)